# android:fitsSystemWindows not working

Tags: android, android-view

In my theme I defined the following rules to draw my views behind the status bar:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

And in the Activity (onCreate):

```
getWindow.getDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
)
```

Then, in my View im using a Barcodescanner that is supposed to draw behind the status bar, which is working. However when I apply the `android:fitsSystemWindows` to any child view they don't get their position adjusted. It's working when I apply it to the root element, though.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <my.Scanner
        android:id="@+id/scanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> <!-- Should receive a top padding, right? -->

        <View android:layout_width="50dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:background="@color/red" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: please accept my solution as correct friend

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My problem was most likely related to multiple/nested `fitsSystemWindows` attributes which does not work as I found out later. I solved my problem by applying the attribute to one view, and then copy the paddings to other views that need them via an `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`. That is an ugly hack, but does its job for now.

Comment: I also had problems when I tried to use fitsSystemWindows on two views in a hierarchy. I solved it when I put those two views in a container and set fitsSystemWindows for that container

Comment: @netimen your solution works best for me. Very clean and simple!!

Comment: I upgraded the build tools from 23 to 25 and same this happened to me. Got fixed by removing nested fitsSystemWindows.

Answer (score 23):

Use CoordinatorLayout as root for your view, it worked for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Comment: Same here, I noticed using android:fitsSystemWindows="true" worked on the DrawerLayout in my first activity but was having no effect in a second activity on a FrameLayout. Maybe only ViewGroups from the support design library really support this attribute?

Answer (score 5):

I meet the same problem in Android 4.4

My problem is                 `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

conflict with `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>`

**My way is remove** 
`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was that the keypad hides an editText field which is placed at the end of the activity ..I have tried every solution out there and nothing works.
I was using this code before the call to `setContentView()` method to make the status bar transparent:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```

I removed it and also removed `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" from the maneifest` file and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this. Make sure you set the 2 elements in styles of the theme applied to your activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ....
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

No need to do add `android:fitsSystemWindows` in your layout. This will directly add to it.

Answer (score -2):

**Make this changes**

```
1. Manifest - create a theme and add window background of your like
2. toolbar in xml -  add the same background in toolbar
```

this works for me.